# Overflow-y: auto cuts absolutely positioned element on left. Solution to move the element on scroll

Tags: html, css

I'm through multiple questions, many answers, and solution, and found an almost perfect one (the element acts fixed positioned). Here's my example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.panel {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 20vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  top: 0;
  left: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: gray;
}
.best-sol {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}

.should-work .content-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1;
}

.inner-scroll {
  background-color: aqua;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content-wrapper{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="panel should-work">
  <p>Should work</p>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="inner-scroll">
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
          <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel best-sol">
  <p>Best solution so far</p>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="inner-scroll">
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
          <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body
```

Ideally .content shouldn't stay at the bottom of the window while scrolling. It should appear at the end. What I want is to let .content, the red box be out of the scroll container, but move with the scroll.

The above is the closest solution. Ideally (but maybe my thinking is wrong) setting the content-wrapper relatively positioned should solve the problem, but it cuts content down.

Any ideas?

Comment: Give a fixed height instead of height in %. Then you will get a scroll.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: I do not exactly understand your problem, is it that you want to fit the wrapper inside the panel and make it scrollable?

Comment: Edited the question with more details, thanks.

Comment: @GergőHorváth I couldn't understand. `.content should appear at the end` and `move with the scroll`. Aren't these two contradictory? Please clearify your question

Answer (score 0):

Make the content css as -

```
.content {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    background-color: red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

And it will behave the way you have shown in the 'should work' example. Also the width in content-wrapper to be 200px for this to work.

```
.content-wrapper{
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: The should work is an example of the expected ideal solution but it doesn't work (as it cuts the red box down). Your solution cuts it down as well. The solution would be to combine the two. Position from the should work example and width from the best solution so far example.

Comment: Ah, let me try that :)

Comment: Try the the edit, and let me know if I understood it correctly this time.